# Bootstrap Row positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a row with an image, and then in a new row with some text I would like to go over that image. I am able to do this with negative margins and other spacing, but I need help for when it comes to a responsive page. As I change the browser size, I'm noticing that new row of text moving to other areas higher than the image. Let me know how I would fix that text exactly where Id want on the row above, and keep it responsive. Thanks!

Heres a gist to my code incase its confusing:

HTML
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5834935

CSS
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5834943

Comment: background-image in the row with the text? It will solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference - here is the outcome [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uqevis/2/)

*missing the media query on the jsbin for greater resolutions*

Glad I could be of help ^-^

Comment: So, I am trying to do this, but the image is being cutoff. If i set the pixel parameters for the image, the responsive feature then wont work. Can you suggest where I should go from here? I've set the container with an id, and given that id the background image.

Comment: update: following this jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2HjcV/3/ I was able to get the background to be somewhat fluid. However, it is now pulling to the right. How would I set the margins to push it to the center and make it work responsively as well? Also, when I am putting in the text fields as mentioned above, I am still having to set the margins with pixels to move them, causing it to space werid on browser size. here is an update to my html and css: HTML:https://gist.github.com/vpoola88/5852507  CSS:https://gist.github.com/vpoola88/5852512

Comment: Sure, can we move this link to chat? I can add you to my github repo for the project if that works better.

Comment: Im not sure how to start a chat actually. Can you initiate it? I thought there was a link to do so, but I dont see it on my end.

Comment: Just go into one of the rooms or e-mail me : lloanalas@live.com